# Add the direction of a curve with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$s$},ylabel={$c$},legend pos=south east]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot+[blue, samples=40, variable=\zeta, domain=10:25]
({(0.1 + 0.4)/2 + 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))},
{1/(2*zeta)*(-0.1)/((0.1 + 0.4)/2 + 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 
2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1)) - 0.1) + (0.1 + 0.4)/2 +  1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 
+ 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))});
\addlegendentry{$P^\ast$}
\addplot+[red, samples=40, variable=\zeta, domain=10:25]
({(0.1 + 0.4)/2 - 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))},
{1/(2*zeta)*(-0.1)/((0.1 + 0.4)/2 - 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 
2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1)) - 0.1) + (0.1 + 0.4)/2 -  1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 
+ 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))});
\addlegendentry{$P^\dagger$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the following image:

[image]

However, I would like to add the "direction" of the curves, i.e. the direction in which they increase. E.g., in the picture this direction is inside-out. What's a way to obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$s$},ylabel={$c$},legend pos=south east,
enlargelimits=0.2]
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot+[blue, samples=40, variable=\zeta, domain=10:25]
({(0.1 + 0.4)/2 + 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))},
{1/(2*zeta)*(-0.1)/((0.1 + 0.4)/2 + 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 
2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1)) - 0.1) + (0.1 + 0.4)/2 +  1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 
+ 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))})
node[midway,above=2ex,sloped,single arrow,fill,text=white,font=\sffamily]
{increasing};
\addlegendentry{$P^\ast$}
\addplot+[red, samples=40, variable=\zeta, domain=10:25]
({(0.1 + 0.4)/2 - 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))},
{1/(2*zeta)*(-0.1)/((0.1 + 0.4)/2 - 1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 + 
2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1)) - 0.1) + (0.1 + 0.4)/2 -  1/2*sqrt((0.1 - 0.4)^2 
+ 2*0.2*1/(0.05*zeta)*(-0.1))})
node[midway,above=2ex,sloped,single arrow,fill,text=white,font=\sffamily,
shape border rotate=180]
{increasing};
\addlegendentry{$P^\dagger$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to draw the arrow on the curve?

Comment: @Mark Yes. Just drop `above=2ex,`. But in that case I would add something like `opacity=0.5`.